# Find unused code in web application

Tags: python, coverage.py

I'm working on a monolithic legacy web application, which we want to try and dismantle. I want to figure out what parts of the code are never run. Is it possible to run `uwsgi` with `coverage`, and if yes, how do I go about it?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? Might reveal something: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html  http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/

Comment: You can use the unit testing support from Flask to get useful coverage reports: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/testing/ The "Flask Mega Tutorial" explains how to set up coverage reports here: http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xvi-debugging-testing-and-profiling

Answer (score 1):

Python coverage has an API. Have a look at the [docs](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/api.html).

You should be able to do `cov.start()` before the app construction. How to stop it and make a report may be a bit harder... Maybe you can register an `atexit` handler?